# web.xml configuration to load html files directly

Tags: web-applications, servlets, jboss

I need to setup a web app in JBoss to load html files directly from a .war file.
What do i need to add to the web.xml file to enable this?

This is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>ws</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>SIMDS</res-ref-name>
        <mapped-name>SIMDS</mapped-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so much what you need to add but what you need to change.  If you look at the servlet-mapping for CXFServlet, you are specifying that all requests to the context of the application are to be mapped to that servlet.

Put more specificity there and you should be able to access HTML files directly from the context assuming they are in the correct location in the WAR file.

Comment: Is there a way that will allow filtering only *.html files and redirecting them to the browser without changing the existing configuration?

Comment: A messy way might be that you could map *.html to an HTML servlet.  I can't remember if a convenience one exists or not but you could easily enough write a servlet that accepts a request for an HTML file, retrieve that requested file, output its text to the response stream, and then your servlet will effectively serve the appropriate HTML content that was requested.